# Tagging s3 objects with streaming file sink

Tags: apache-flink

I want to tag s3 objects created with the s3a filesystem plugin for flink 1.10. A pipeline should define how to tag s3 objects created with the streamingfilesink. The API does not yet support this feature but could easily be added by eg. overloading initiateMultiPartUpload of InternalWriteOperationHelper of HadoopS3AccessHelper and passing the necessary tag information to InitiateMultipartUploadRequest with setTagging. I want to submit a patch for this.

Are there any concerns from the community for this feature?

Comment: Discussions like this belong on the dev@flink.apache.org mailing list. stackoverflow is more appropriate for getting help than for proposing new features. Note that you'll need to subscribe via an email to dev-subscribe@flink.apache.org before you can post to the list.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow that route